# InMobi Integration with AdWhirl 3.0

Tags: iphone, adwhirl, inmobi

hi
i am creating app to display ads at bottom.
i am done all the requirements to fulfill the ads.

when i am run my app i got the following message in my console
 InMobi:Error! rootViewControllerForAd method must be implemented. Cannot serve InMobi Ads.
2011-04-19 10:35:42.177 Real Scale Highly Accurate[393:207] InMobi:Error! rootViewControllerForAd method must be implemented. Cannot serve InMobi Ads.

what's the problem i don't know.
for InMobi ads I just add only its InMobiAdView.h header in my viewController.m else i perfectly done all Adwhirl methods and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS InMobi adpater for AdWhirl 3.0 is not up-to-date, you need to use these:

- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11489287/AdWhirlAdapterInMobi.h
- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11489287/AdWhirlAdapterInMobi.m

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in `InMobiAdDelegate.h` this method is marked as `@required`. So to solve this in `AdWhirlAdapterInMobi.m` add method

```
- (UIViewController *)rootViewControllerForAd {
   return [adWhirlDelegate viewControllerForPresentingModalView];
}
```

That worked for me.